# Xml document displaying

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I found one code on w3school which should display xml file in table format. I'm trying to make this work with my file, but I can't get it.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <style>
  table,th,td {
 border : 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  }
   th,td {
  padding: 5px;
    }
  </style>
  <body>

   <button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Get my CD collection</button>
   <br><br>
    <table id="demo"></table>


   <script>
   function loadXMLDoc() {
   var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
  myFunction(this);
   }
   };
   xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://newfmplayer.online/AirPlayHistory.xml",       true);
  xmlhttp.send();
 }
 function myFunction(xml) {
 var i;
   var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var table="<tr><th>name</th><th>Song title</th></tr>";
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Song");
  for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
   table += "<tr><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
   "</td><td>" +
   x[i].getElementsByTagName("Song title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
   "</td></tr>";
    }
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
 }
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Link to my file : https://newfmplayer.online/AirPlayHistory.xml
Original code from w3schools : https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=tryxml_display_table

Comment: Please check console for any error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, actually in your xml file, attributes contain values.
In w3school example, node itself contain values.
So, basically you need to access node attributes, not the node (element) itself.

Follow [This link on w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/dom_nodes_nodelist.asp) to access attributes:

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Testing XMLHttpRequest</title>
<style type="text/css">
  table,th,td {border : 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; }
   th,td { padding: 5px; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadXMLDoc() {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                myFunction(this);
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "AirPlayHistory.xml", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
    function myFunction(xml) {
        var i;
        var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
        var table = "<tr><th>name</th><th>Song title</th></tr>";
        var songTitles = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Song");
        var artistNames = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Artist");
        for (i = 0; i < songTitles.length; i++) {
            table += "<tr><td>" + artistNames[i].attributes.getNamedItem("name").nodeValue + "</td><td>" + 
                    songTitles[i].attributes.getNamedItem("title").nodeValue + "</td></tr>";
        }
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Get my CD collection</button>
    <br/><br/>
    <table id="demo"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried replacing document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table; with    x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Song")[0].attributes;
txt = x.getNamedItem("title").nodeValue; , it did not work,, did I something wrong, or should do something else?

Comment: Sorry, but still nothing happening, I also tried changing on different id, but nothing

Comment: Please check console for any error ? Press Ctrl + Shift + J

Comment: it says loadXMLDoc' is not defined, what should I do?

Comment: Well, I take time to create a full html document example for you. I edited my answer. It is working for me on local system. Please copy paste full html code in new file to test at your local system